# Android Jetpack Navigation Component issue with edit text masks and error messages

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack, android-architecture-navigation, input-mask

I'm trying to use [android-input-mask](https://github.com/RedMadRobot/input-mask-android) by [RedMadRobot](https://github.com/RedMadRobot) in my Android Kotlin project. But currently, I'm dealing with very strange behavior. The library only works when I disable the Android Navigation Component.

My `activity_main.xml` layout has the following fragment:

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/nav_host"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
    app:navGraph="@navigation/navigation"
    app:defaultNavHost="true"/>
```

Then, in the start destination defined in the navigation component I have:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/test"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:digits="1234567890+-() "
    { omitted for sake of simplicity } />
```

Finally, in the the `SignUpFragment.kt` file I have these lines of code:

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    val listener = MaskedTextChangedListener.installOn(
        test,
        "+7 ([000]) [000]-[00]-[00]",
        object : MaskedTextChangedListener.ValueListener {
            override fun onTextChanged(maskFilled: Boolean, extractedValue: String, formattedValue: String) {
                Log.d("TAG", extractedValue)
                Log.d("TAG", maskFilled.toString())
            }
        }
    )
    test.hint = listener.placeholder()
}
```

But it does not works, as you can see in the following image:

[image: Mask is not applyed]

However, when I hard code the signup fragment in the `activity_main.xml` file all works fine:

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment"
    android:name="my.app.SignUpFragment"
    { omitted for sake of simplicity } />
```

[image: mask is applyed]

**My question is:** is there any plausible explanation for this "bug"? Am I making some confusion? How can I solve it?

Thanks for the help.

**EDIT:**

Same behavior for error messages. If I put this line of code:

```
test.error = "Error message"
```

using Android Navigation Component no error message is shown. However, if I hard code the fragment in the main activity layout, the error message is displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after a lot of time spent in searching for answers, I found that my issue is related to the Android Data Binding Library. More specifically, I need to set listeners and the error message in the binding object created in the `onCreateView` of my `SignUpFragment`, as follows:

```
private lateinit var binding: FragmentSignUpBinding

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sign_up, container, false)

    // saving the instance of FragmentSignUpBinding
    binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(activity!!, R.layout.fragment_sign_up)

    binding.signupViewModel = signUpViewModel

    binding.lifecycleOwner = this

    setObservers()

    return view
}
```

then, in the `onViewCreated`:

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    MaskedTextChangedListener.installOn(
        binding.editCpf, // insted of simply edit_cpf
        "[000].[000].[000]-[00]",
        object : MaskedTextChangedListener.ValueListener {
            override fun onTextChanged(maskFilled: Boolean, extractedValue: String, formattedValue: String) {
                Log.d("TAG", extractedValue)
                Log.d("TAG", maskFilled.toString())
            }
        }
    )

}
```

and then it works fine.